# Shiny server docker app runs locally but not when deployed to AWS Fargate

Tags: r, docker, shiny-server, aws-fargate

I have a containerized `R` Shiny app that, when run locally with `docker run --rm -p 3838:3838 [image]` works as expected. The "landing" page appears when I go to `localhost:3838` and all is good. However, when this container is deployed to AWS Fargate, things break down. The container appears to start and run, but there's no webpage being served on `3838` even though all ports are pointed to `3838` in Fargate.

I'm using dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/verse:3.5.1

LABEL Steven "email"

## Add shiny capabilities to container
RUN export ADD=shiny && bash /etc/cont-init.d/add

## Update and install 
RUN tlmgr update --self 
RUN tlmgr install beamer translator

## Add R packages
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'googleAuthR', 'dplyr', 'googleAnalyticsR', 'knitr', 'rmarkdown', 'jsonlite', 'scales', 'ggplot2', 'reshape2', 'Cairo', 'tinytex'), repos = 'https://cran.rstudio.com/')"

#Copy app dir and them dirs to their respective locations
COPY app /srv/shiny-server/ga-reporter
COPY app/report/themes/SwCustom /opt/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/

#Force texlive to find my custom beamer thems
RUN texhash

EXPOSE 3838

## Add shiny-server information
COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh
COPY shiny-customized.config /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf

## Add dos2unix to eliminate Win-style line-endings and run
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
RUN dos2unix /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

and `shiny-server.conf`

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    app_dir /srv/shiny-server/ga-reporter;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

with `shiny-server.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

# ShinyServer: Make sure the directory for individual app logs exists
mkdir -p /var/log/shiny-server
chown -R shiny.shiny /var/log/shiny-server

# RUN ShinyServer
exec shiny-server >> /var/log/shiny-server.log 2>&1
```

I have edited the `.conf` file to display the app (i.e., `location /`) in `/srv/shiny-server/ga-reporter` which is also where I've copied the `app_dir` in the Dockerfile. Shiny is listening on port `3838` and should serve the page there. Again, this happens locally but not when deployed to AWS Fargate. I've tried logging Shiny logs to `stdout` by using [the first answer provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48874782/4351030) but have had no luck seeing any errors generated. [Server "health checking" is only offered in the "pro" version so I can't check to see if the server is actually running.](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#health-check-endpoint)

On AWS, the container starts and appears to function normally (i.e., the "normal" start up logs appear):

[image]

but there is simply no page displayed at the location I expect it to be served.

I found [another Shiny app that is on dockerhub running under the same configuration as the Fargate cluster](https://github.com/QuantumObject/docker-shiny)  but have had no luck trying to implement anything in the `shiny-server.conf` or the `shiny-server.sh` files located there.

What am I missing? Everything on Fargate is pointed to listening on `3838`; there must be something I'm missing in the `.conf` file for this to be failing when deployed.

---

**EDIT**

I can't bash in to the running container on Fargate because I don't have access to the server on which docker is running.

Fargate has a UI that accepts host and container ports:

[image]

---

**EDIT 2** (2018-08-27)

The engineer that was deploying this has been able to resolve the issue:

*"it was the port change, I forgot to can the port on the ALB’s security group, I only updated the cluster’s inbound rules*

*so the cluster was allowing connections, but the ALB security group wasn’t letting it out"*

Comment: The link to the other shiny app points to a running shiny server, not some code repository. Which files are you talking about?

Comment: I know nothing about AWS Fargate. People who know it might want to know, how you did the analogue of `-p 3838:3838` from the docker command line, i.e.  how you published port 3838 of the container as port 3838 on the host.

Comment: @RalfStubner Apologies. I changed the link to go to the github page. Thanks. Also, Fargate has a UI for editing the host/container ports. I included a screen shot of the ports. Not sure how much that helps though.

Comment: What does your security group for the task ENI look like?

Comment: "there is simply no page displayed at the location I expect it to be served" What is this location? <public_ip>:3838, or something else?

Comment: You say that the "landing page" is displayed when run locally. But then you configure `/` to show a certain app. Did you locally test the image you want to deploy on Fargate? Does it display your app?

Comment: @bluescores We're using `awsvpc`; I'll check in with the engineer that's handling this deployment for more specifics. The container and app it's exposing are behind our company's VPN, so `ga-reporter.devops-staywell.com`.

@RalfStubner Maybe "landing page" wasn't correct. Yes, I've locally tested the image I'm trying to deploy. Yes, it displays my app. I tried configuring `/` in the hopes that adjusting the config would resolve the issue. It did not.

Comment: FYI if you configure the container to run `sshd` you can ssh to it directly, if that's helpful to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Can you map the 3838 port to 80 instead?  Perhaps that is more supported

Comment: I'm very interested in seeing if it works on Fargate

Comment: Apparently, the enginner that was deploying this app found the error: 

*"it was the port change, I forgot to can the port on the ALB’s security group, I only updated the cluster’s inbound rules. so the cluster was allowing connections, but the ALB security group wasn’t letting it out"*